# Rearrange String to Form Palindrome in C

Tags: c, string, palindrome

Given a string in C.

How can I rearrange the given string so it form a palindrome?

Is there a way to implement it in `O(n)` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity?

Comment: A simple implementation in `O(n)` time and `O(c)` (number of distinct characters) space would be to loop through the string counting the number of occurrences of each character, and then loop through it again, constructing the palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool canFormPalindrome(string str)
{
    // Create a count array and initialize all
    // values as 0
    int count[NO_OF_CHARS] = { 0 };
 
    // For each character in input strings,
    // increment count in the corresponding
    // count array
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
        count[str[i]]++;
 
    // Count odd occurring characters
    int odd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS; i++) {
        if (count[i] & 1)
            odd++;
 
        if (odd > 1)
            return false;
    }
 
    // Return true if odd count is 0 or 1,
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The complexity is O(n)

Comment: But this doesn't rearrange the given array! It just returns true of false ...

Comment: @SrikrishnaSharma But, I can form a palindrome with three (odd number of) same characters: `aaa`